# Kendo MVC UI ComboBox Dictionary<int,string> Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

How to bind type Dictionary to Kendo Combobox?

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
.Name("Division")
.DataTextField("Key")
.DataValueField("Value")
.BindTo(Model.Filter.DivisionList)
)
```

Model.Filter.DivisionList is Dictionary
With above code I have an error "not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects."

Is there a simple workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`
To get it, you can use simple query:

```
var selectList = Model.Filter.DivisionList.Select(c=>new SelectListItem{Text = c.Value, Value = c.Key.ToString()});
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
.Name("PaymentTerm"
).BindTo(
   new SelectList(Model.CreditCollectionInfo.PaymentTerms.Select(
         s => new {
             Key = s.Key, 
             Value = s.Value
         }
), "Key", "Value")
```